# Persistent HTTPS Connections Objective-C iOS Cocoa

Tags: ios, cocoa, https, persistent

What's the best way to make persistent HTTPS connections in Objective-C with Cocoa Framework for iPhone with NSURLSession? I've read somewhere else that persistent connections are standard since HTTP 1.1. Some code example would be very appreciated. I need to achieve a simple data retrieval task (json encoded string)

best regards
stefan

Comment: The book "iOS Programming for iPhone and iPad" by Joe Conway/Aaron Hillegass would be a great source starting http-NSURLConnections. I am not familiar with that theme, so I hope this helps you comming forward. Good luck.

Comment: thank you macrene. but i want to use nsurlsession, not nsurlconnection. is there something about this in the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link http://www.objc.io/issue-5/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession.html to find out, what "no persistent" means to understand "persistent".

I haven't used NSURLConnection or NSURLSession myself, but persistent is not a special setting. It means, that the same settings-data is used for connection/session.

Comment: thank you for this excellent link! what i want to achieve is the following: 'HTTP persistent connection, also called HTTP keep-alive, or HTTP connection reuse, is the idea of using a single TCP connection to send and receive multiple HTTP requests/responses, as opposed to opening a new connection for every single request/response pair.' - wikipedia. when i reuse the same settings-data, is the same tcp connection also reused? the 'sepcial setting' is the keep-alive in the http header from my understanding.

Comment: A tcp connection is a kind of road (connection) between two places (websites). The TCP/IP protocol only assures, that these sites can communicate. The connections-way for the sended/received data ALWAYS depends on which "road" is actually free. And I strongly recommend, read the mentioned book. Success.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing about NSURLSession...

But I've found a tutorial here
http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial.

Comment: thank you! but persistent connections are not mentioned in this tutorial.